# How to test if a variable exists in MVC3 razor layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm just digging in to .NET views with the razor syntax. Most of my coding knowledge is in javascript so this is probably a basic question (or my approach is completely wrong!). In my html, I am building dns prefetch tags based on an array declared at the top of template. Maybe I am approaching this wrong because of my javascript background, but if one of my views doesn't need any pre-fetch tags, I'd like to avoid declaring the DNSPrefetch variable.

How can I test if a variable exists, and then execute some code based on the result? I got it to work using a try/catch, but was thinking that there is a better way. Thanks!

In _Layout (working with try/catch):

```
  @{
    try {
      foreach (var dns in ViewBag.DNSPrefetch) {
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//@dns" />
      }
    }
    catch{}
  }
```

In template:

```
  @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    // DNS prefetching for improved performance. More reading: http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/DNS-Prefetching/
    string[] DNSArray = { "ajax.googleapis.com", "mpsnare.iesnare.com" };
    ViewBag.DNSPrefetch = DNSArray;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just check if the value is null:

```
@{
  if (ViewBag.DNSPrefetch != null) {
    foreach (var dns in ViewBag.DNSPrefetch) {
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//@dns" />
    }
  }
}
```

(Alternatively, you could declare DNSArray as an empty array when it's not needed, then you could use the *foreach* block as-is for all cases.)

Comment: Sigh. I _should_ have been able to figure that out on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error is because null does not provide an iterator so when the foreach begins it throws an exception. Use a conditional to check to see if the value is in the viewbag first.

```
@{
 if( ViewBag.DNSPrefect != null ){
  foreach (var dns in ViewBag.DNSPrefetch) {
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//@dns" />
  }
 }
}
```

However, this *should* be done in your view model. Use a strongly typed view model to accomplish this. You would compose the view model in your controller action, then pass the view model into the view which would be strongly typed to that view model. This will allow you to use the foreach loop on a `string[]` without worrying about if it is null because the value will already be initialized as empty if nothing is added.

view model `SomeActionVM.cs`

```
public class SomeActionVM
{
 public string[] DNSArray { get; set; }
 //other variables to pass in
}
```

action:

```
// Get: SomeAction
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
 var vm = new SomeActionVM();
 vm.DNSArray = { "ajax.googleapis.com", "mpsnare.iesnare.com" };
 return View(vm);
}
```

view:

```
@model namespace.SomeActionVM

@foreach (var dns in Model.DNSPrefetch) {
    @:<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//@dns" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for also showing the proper way to do it. I'll try to implement this later. I accepted dbaseman's answer since it was first.